# How can I fetch data with an array in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to get all data of the applicants in an array:

Here is following code that how I fetch an array:

```
const [applicants, setTeamApplications] = useState([]);

  const fetchApplicationData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/v1/invites/team/applications/${teamId}`);

 const items = res.data.map((item) =>
  await axios.get(`/api/v1/profiles/profile/${item.applicant_publicId}`)
);

    // Set state
    setTeamApplications(res.data);
    // Toggle loading state
    setLoadingState(false);
  };
```

after I `console.log(applicants)`

it gave me this:

```
[{…}]
0:
applicant_publicId: "La1618912810062"
application_letter: "apply"
id: 3
response: "Waiting on review"
```

Now im trying to fetch data again with the `applicant_publicId` to get more data:

`/api/v1/profiles/profile/${index.applicant_publicId}`

How can I do that?

Comment: Where are you trying to fetch more data? Please update your question and code snippet and show us.

Comment: You can use the find method and save the id needed in variable then use that.

Comment: @DrewReese just updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `await` inside the `.map` callback as it is synchronous, but you can map the response data to an array of requests for the profiles and use `Promise.all` and wait for them all to resolve to an array of profiles.

```
const [applicants, setTeamApplications] = useState([]);

const fetchApplicationData = async () => {
  // Toggle loading state
  setLoadingState(true);

  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/v1/invites/team/applications/${teamId}`);

    const profileReqs = res.data.map((item) =>
      axios.get(`/api/v1/profiles/profile/${item.applicant_publicId}`)
    );

    const items = await Promise.all(profileReqs);

    // Set state
    setTeamApplications(res.data);
    setProfiles(items);

  } catch (error) {
    // handler any error state?
  } finally {
    // Toggle loading state
    setLoadingState(false);
  }
};
```